# hive-site.xml doesn't override default properties

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-hive

I'm trying to override hive default properties by setting them in `hive-site.xml` but it's not taking any effect. Few things that might be helpful in debugging the problem:

1. Environment variables:

   `HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf
   HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HIVE_HOME/conf:$HIVE_HOME/lib
   HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$HIVE_HOME/lib`
2. Permissions: I have given `777` permission to entire hive directory
   (I know it should be `733` and I'm not supposed to make it `777` but for
   testing's sake I did it)
3. Valid XML: I thought it could be invalid xml but xsl definition
   and tags are intact and valid. No issue in xml.
4. `hive-env.sh` is being read but can't say about `hive-site.xml`

Please comment if any other details are required.

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: how do you start hive? is there any hive-site.xml or hive-defaults.xml file in the folder you are starting hive from?